# Is there any way for Google Analytics to track multiple event parameters like Mixpanel?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Given:

```
_trackEvent(category, action, opt_label, opt_value, opt_noninteraction)
```

I tried with opt_label but it seems like it's just a string and doesn't accept a hash of different parameters like Mixpanel do.

I suspect one of the the work around is using custom variables? But the docs seems confusing. Appreciate any advice.

Comment: What type of element are you tacking?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

While you can certainly make this work in Google Analytics, other analytics services like Mixpanel, KISSmetrics, Kontagent, etc specialize in event analysis and give you more flexibility. Having said that, you can hack the Google Analytics event model to get what you’re looking for.

If you want to track multiple parameters for each event in Google Analytics I’d suggest cramming the parameters you want to track into the event label. This is workable for two reasons: Event labels can be really long (ridiculously long, actually) and Google Analytics provides flexible filtering and segmentation options.

So, to extend an example discussed in an earlier answer, you could have an event for tracking video play details that looks like this:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 'title:MoreCatLolz, 
    percentPlayed:63, adShown:true, res:480p, fullScreen:false']);
```

All we've done is toss a few arbitrary parameters into the event label string in such a way that we can pull them out later. To analyze the results you could filter your event reports to show, say, the number of times the ‘MoreCatLolz’ video was shown with ads:

[image: Number of times MoreCatLolz was shown with ads]

Alternately, using advanced segments and regex, you could count the number of visits in which users watched at least 90% of any video:

[image: Number of visits in which users watched at least 90% of any video]

To track persistent user data, such as name, join date, level, purchase count, etc., I’d suggest using visitor-level custom variables which are automatically included with every tracking call (including events) and allow you to apply many of the same analysis techniques.

Comment: FYI, these filters are found under `Behavior -> Events -> Top Events` to open an events report, then click `customize` just under the title.

Answer (score 1):

GA is not as good as Mixpanel for tracking event (or hit in general) properties, and maybe you should rethink what you want to/can do in GA. That said, there is a way to achieve what you need with **custom dimensions and metrics**. [Here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en) is some info on what they do, and [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829?hl=en) are instructions on how to set them up in the admin panel, and [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets) you can find how to use them in your code. Some limitations:

> There are 20 indices available for different custom dimensions and 20 indices for custom metrics in each property. 360 accounts have 200 indices available for custom dimensions and 200 for custom metrics.
>
> Custom dimensions cannot be deleted, but you can disable them.

First, you would need to add the custom dimensions/metrics through the admin panel  in GA (Admin -> Properties column -> Custom Definitions -> Custom Dimensions/Metrics).

Using `analytics.js`, you can set the event properties using either `set` before you trigger a hit, or `send` when you trigger a hit. Examples:

```
// set the dimension/metric values before the hit
ga('set', {
  'dimension5': 'custom dimension data',
  'metric5': 8000
});
// values set above are passed to GA along with the hit info
ga('send', 'event', 'someCategory', 'someAction');


// or alternatively
ga('send', 'event', 'someCategory', 'someAction', {
  'dimension5': 'custom dimension data',
  'metric5': 8000
});
```

In case you're not sure what's the difference between dimensions and metrics, check [this](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033861?hl=en) out.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what mixpanel is, so I'm unaware of what you're trying to compare analytics to. If you provided a specific example of the data you're trying to collect, I could provide you with a better answer.

Lets say you have a video player and you want to track how long people watch the video and how many times people paused the video, you would do something like this;

```
if (video == "pause") {
   var playTime = playduration(), // Total minutes of video watched
       clickPause = pauseNum(); // Total number of times video was paused

   _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Video', 'Play', playTime]);
   _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Video', 'Pause', clickPause]);
}
```

Obviously this is generic, but as you can see in the `_gaq.push` arrays, `Play` and `Pause` are the parameters and `playTime` and `clickPause` are the variable values of the parameters.

Comment: Sure I am going to give a random example but i think it works. Say the user object is called person. I also want to know 'person.name' and 'person.location' who clicked that 'Play button', how can I track them ?

Comment: That might be going above and beyond what analytics can do (at least easily anyways).  But lets say you do know the person's name (because they're logged into your site), you can enter that in to `opt_value`.  In analytics you can also drill down events by location.  There are tons of options, you just have to expirement with them.

Comment: google analytics automatically tracks location, so that might be a bad example but you get the gist i think. If I want to say track 5 other user specific attributes, _trackEvent limits the number of stuff you can sent in.

Answer (score -2):

The label is optional, so I would expand it to something like:

```
<a href="#" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Games', 'Play', 'Tetris']);">Play</a>
```

Category = 'Games'
Event = 'Play'
Label = 'Tetris'

Comment: Ya those are the standard, but I want to add more parameters