# Google Analytics: Event tracking with multiple labels

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, universal-analytics

What is the best way to track a Google Analytics Event with multiple labels?

Here is my situation:

A user can view a list of videos of food.  A user can filter the videos by Country and Color.  A user can select to filter by multiple Countries and multiple colors.  Examples of countries is Mexico, USA, China, Italy.  Examples of Colors is Red, Blue, Green, Yellow.

With Google Analytics, I want to track when a user filters the list of videos.  When they a user filters, I want to know what that a filter was applied and which Countries and which Colors were selected.

The Label of the Event tracked can be used to indicate which Countries and which Colors as a commas separated value.  But what if I want to view ALL events that had Mexico as a country including when it wasn't the only country selected.  What is the best way to track this Event?

Answer (score 4):

You can include a number of parameters inside the Labels section, like so:

```
onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'videos', 'filter', 'country: USA, color: red',  1]);"
```

Then, when you want your results in Google Analytics, just create a filter for that event label.

This response really broke it down: [Is there any way for Google Analytics to track multiple event parameters like Mixpanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165184/is-there-any-way-for-google-analytics-to-track-multiple-event-parameters-like-mi)