# How to pass multiple variables in GA Events?

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

In Google Analytics we can pass value as by document

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

How to pass multiple variables at the same time instead of 2 calls?

```
onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'favorite', 'type','a');"
onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'favorite', 'id',100);"
```

I would like to pass both in only 1 call. How to do it?

Comment: This will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165184/is-there-any-way-for-google-analytics-to-track-multiple-event-parameters-like-mi

Comment: @NitinDhomse thats from 2012 and not even using the current JS library do you think its going to work now?

Comment: Why you don't use the new gtag library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pass more information/context about an event, your best bet would be to make use of hit-scoped [custom dimensions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en). In your specific case, you would define two hit-scoped custom dimensions in GA (`type` and `id`). Once these are defined, they will each be assigned an index. Then in your tracking code, you would simply do the following:

```
ga('set', 'cd1', 'La');
ga('set', 'cd2', '100');
ga('send', 'event', 'favorite');
```

You would then be able to use your custom dimensions either as secondary dimensions in the standard Google Analytics reports or in [custom reports](https://support.google.com/analytics/).

You are allowed a maximum of 20 custom dimension in Google Analytics standard (the free version).